# Test S3 PUT/write permissions without actually writing any files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a set of s3 credentials (access key and secret key).

Is there a way to test if this has write access (specifically PUT) on a bucket without actually writing any files?

Main reason is I may have PUT access but not DELETE access so don't want to add files I can't remove.

Comment: You could try [Testing IAM policies with the IAM policy simulator - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html), but I'm not sure whether it will test the Bucket Policy on the bucket. Give it a try!